# How do you put a Terraria template on without a bak world on Mac?

Tags: terraria

This is a template I just got 1.4.1.1 but I don't know how to use it.
None of my searches worked.

[image]

Comment: None of your searches worked? If [I search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=terraria%20.wld%20file%20mac) I get enough hits on how to use such a file. And what's a "BAK world"? A .bak or backup file of the current world?

Comment: yes a backup file sorry its my first time doing this so i dont know much

Comment: That is no problem, @dameon, but you have to be detailed with your phrasing. What is the situation, and what are you attempting to do? Be descriptive and detailed. It's maybe helpful to just write down the steps you've taken, and then what you want to achieve.

Comment: So my friend gave me his world we played on because he stopped playing but when I put the file in the worlds folder it says can't find the backup file. I'm also on MacBook so I don't know if I'm doing it wrong so.